# What were the clues that Dixon missed in "Three Billboards"?

Tags: plot-explanation, three-billboards-outside-ebbing

The Wikipedia plot summary has this bit near the end, emphasis mine:

> Abercrombie informs Dixon that the DNA sample does not match DNA found on Angela's body and that the man was overseas on military duty and had come back to the country 9 months before. **Dixon stays confused and does not connect the clues.**

What clues? What was Dixon unable to figure out?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The clues of the whereabouts of the DNA guy 9 months ago. Dixon was not able to figue out the country the guy was in 9 months ago using the chief's clues. The chief couldn't just tell him that because it is classified information so he thought of implying it to Dixon using the following clues, respectively:

- The guy has a commanding officer
- The guy got back to the country 9 months ago
- The country where he was is classified
- **Bonus clue:** It was sandy.

Personally, I think the country is Iraq.

Comment: I found the clue about the sand unhelpful because Afghanistan is also a major contender here and it is also thought to be sandy.